# Identify Reference to Destroy & Re-Initialize Swiper in Elementor

Tags: scope, this, destroy, swiper.js, elementor

Elementor Pro (the WordPress page builder) integrates beautifully with [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/), tying their GUI to the JS parameters and database content.

However, for my project, I need to make some changes to the Swiper ["CoverFlow" skin](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#coverflow-effect) Init parameters (show more slides, change the 3D effect facing direction...).

My hope is to to use the [Destroy method](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#methods) of the Swiper API which looks like:

```
mySwiper.destroy(deleteInstance, cleanStyles);
```

Then I can initialize the Swiper again, with my own custom parameters. The challenge is that the way Elementor calls Swiper in [frontend.js](http://masonmagazine.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/js/frontend.js) is a complex anonymous function that doesn't really allow me to know what "mySwiper" would be... On line 567:

```
this.swipers.main = new Swiper(this.elements.$mainSwiper, this.getSwiperOptions());
```

I would be so grateful if someone could please help me understand what "this.swipers.main" would translate to after Init so that I can destroy the swiper and initialize it again with my own parameters.

**Obviously I cannot edit frontend.js itself as it is a plugin file that needs to be updated.**

Extra points for whomever teaches me how to fish and what the methodology is to solve these types of puzzles for other similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can give an ID to the Elementor widget ex: `slider1` and then with JS you can use:

```
var sliderInstance = document.querySelector('#slider1 .swiper-container').swiper;
```

After this you can call `sliderInstance.destroy()` wherever you want.

And if you want to initialize it again you can call:

```
var sliderInstance = new Swiper('#slider1 .swiper-container', {
    //options
});
```

Comment: Bingo.. You sorted my case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this function to initialise Elementor's Carousels and restore arrow and loop functionality:

```
   // Funzione per inizializzare Swiper
    var initializeSwiper = function(carousel) {
      var swiperInstance = carousel.find('.elementor-image-carousel-wrapper').data('swiper');

      // Se esiste già un'istanza di Swiper, distruggila prima di reinizializzarla
      if (swiperInstance) {
        swiperInstance.destroy(true, true);
      }

      // Inizializza nuovamente Swiper
      var swiper = new Swiper(carousel.find('.elementor-image-carousel-wrapper'), {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.elementor-swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.elementor-swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
        },
    loop: true, // Abilita il loop
        // Altre opzioni desiderate qui
      });
    };
    // END Funzione per inizializzare Swiper
 initializeSwiper($(".wrapCarouselNAME"));
```